# Calculating Struck calculating Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{kx}\; \; x<0$ and $0$ for $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{kx},& (x<0)\\  0, & (x>0).\end{cases}$$ where $k>0$

Fourier transform for $f(x)$ is $f_T(w)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-\iota wx}dx$

substituting :

$f_T(w)= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{kx}e^{-\iota wx}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{(k-\iota w)x}dx$

Now how do I decide the behaviour of $e^{(k-\iota w)x}$ as $x\to -\infty$?

Comment: You can calculate the integral now by change of variables. Can you go on with that?

Comment: @Jack I figured it out using $e^{\iota x}=cos(x)+\iota \sin(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{(k-i\omega)x}|_{x=-\infty} = e^{kx}e^{-i\omega x}|_{x=-\infty} \leq e^{kx}\|e^{-i\omega x}\| |_{x=-\infty}=0$.

Comment: I realised that in $e^{a+ \iota b}$, sign of $a$ dominates what happens at $\pm \infty$ using  $e^{\iota x}=cos(x)+\iota \sin(x)$. You gave an easy argument for it. thanks